# Set Cover Heuristic

Tags: python, heuristic

[The set-cover problem is explained here.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem)

I am using lists that are being treated as sets. As I found lists were easier to manipulate in python than sets.

The first part of the algorithm uses input validation.

```
import json
from copy import deepcopy
import random

s =  input("Input list of integers (no repeating elements) for S with commas (eg. 1,2,3,4...) : ").split(',')
c =  input('enter list for C (eg. [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]): ')
c = json.loads(c)
s = [int(a) for a in s]

random.seed()
miss = []
delete = []
remove = []
remove_t=[]
no = 0
def input_validation():
    # checking for missing elements.
    no = 0
    for a in range(0, len(c)):
        for b in range(0, len(c[a])):
            miss.append(c[a][b])
    for d in s:
        if d not in miss:
            print('False', d)
            no = 1
            break
    if no == 1:
        quit()
    # Throw out unwanted orderings of sub-lists
    for a in range(0, len(c)):
        c[a] = sorted(c[a])
    # Lists are treated as sets, so lists
    # with repeating elements is thrown out        
    for rem in range(0, len(c)):
        if len(c[rem]) != len(set(c[rem])):
            remove.append(c[rem])
    for rem_two in range(0, len(remove)):
        if remove[rem_two] in c:
            del c[c.index(remove[rem_two])]
    # Throw out lists that have elements that do
    # not exist in s.
    for j in range(0, len(c)):
        for jj in range(0, len(c[j])):
            if any(elem not in s for elem in c[j]):
                remove_t.append(c[j])
    for rem_two in range(0, len(remove_t)):
        if remove_t[rem_two] in c:
            del c[c.index(remove_t[rem_two])]
```

The Second Part of the Algorithm uses a bijective mapping that will prepare it for the heart of the program. There is a function, I found on the internet that shuffles the list. I already know that Python has a shuffling function. But, I wasn't sure, if it would be able to generate all permutations of the list; if it ran forever in a while-loop. So far it suffices.

```
s_copy = deepcopy(s)
input_validation()
# remove repeating lists
c = [c[x] for x in range(len(c)) if not(c[x] in c[:x])]
c_copy = deepcopy(c)
one_s = []
# See if there is sets
# with one element.
# and check them for a
# cover.
for a in c:
    if len(a) == 1:
        if a not in one_s:
            one_s.append(a)
if len(one_s) == len(s):
    print(one_s)
    quit()
def bijective_mapp():
    s_copy = deepcopy(s)
    for a in range(0, len(s)):
        s[a] = a+1
    for b in range(0, len(c)):
        for bb in range(0, len(c[b])):
            c[b][bb] = s_copy.index(c[b][bb])+1
bijective_mapp()
c = [sorted(y) for y in c]
def shuff(c, n):
    for i in range(n-1,0,-1):
        j = random.randint(0,i)
        c[i],c[j] = c[j],c[i]
c.append(sorted(c[len(c)-1]))
```

The third and final part of the program sorts the list `C` in a special-way where all `[1,x,x]'s` are grouped together. So are `[4,x,x]'s` with the other `[4,x,x,...]'s`.  When the `reset` variable is met, the list C gets shuffled until the loop reaches `steps` iterations. After the loop ends, I will output the cover with the most sets found.

The variable `steps` are impractical; when the input is large enough. As I need, the largest amount of sets found without running in exponential-time. The reason for the constant shuffling (and sorting) is because it seems to find covers more easily.

```
n = len(s)
steps = n*(2**2)*((n*(2**2))-1)*((n*(2**2))-2)//6
reset = 0
c_elem = set()
set_cover = []
partial = []
for a in range(0, steps + 1):
    reset = reset + 1
    if reset > len(c):
        c_elem = set()
        reset = 0
        shuff(c, len(c))
        c = sorted(c, key=lambda parameter: parameter[0])
        set_cover = []
    c.append(c[0])
    del(c[0])
    for l in c:
        if not any(v in c_elem for v in l):
            set_cover.append(l)
            c_elem.update(l)
    # if exact solution not found,
    # then use partial solution
    if set_cover not in partial:
        partial.append(set_cover)
# get the largest set-cover found
list_of_partials = [len(r) for r in partial]
k = partial[list_of_partials.index(max(list_of_partials))]
# Reversing the Bijective mapping
# to the original input. But, its sorted.
for a in range(0, len(k)):
    for b in range(0, len(k[a])):
        l = s.index(k[a][b])
        k[a][b] = s_copy[l]
# Outputs the largest amount of sets found
print(k)
```

What are some simple optimizations for the function `input_validation` that I could use?

Are there better ways, to improve the efficiency of the nested loops in the third part of the algorithm?

What variable names would you recommend using for the function `input_validation`?

Because, I am coding as a hobby, what is a more pythonic way to make this easier for you to read and understand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Validation

This:

```
c =  input('enter list for C (eg. [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]): ')
c = json.loads(c)
```

may be fine for your purposes if this is a proof-of-concept script, but if you needed rigorous input validation, `loads` allows for too much variation. You also need to check that this is a list of lists of integers and nothing else. Otherwise, the user could provide a dictionary of dictionaries of lists of dictionaries of strings mapping to nulls, and your program would unceremoniously crash.

### Shadowing

You have a big crazy mix of global code interleaved (with no empty lines) with function definitions. Among other things, you'll see strange effects from code like

```
no = 0
def input_validation():
    no = 0
```

Those two `no` variables do *not* refer to the same thing, the latter shadowing the former. Tear out your globals and pass them around via function parameters and return values, or make a class.

### Range defaults

Drop `0,`  from these:

```
for a in range(0, len(c)):
    for b in range(0, len(c[a])):
```

### Sets

> I am using lists that are being treated as sets. As I found lists were easier to manipulate in python than sets.

That's... ominous, and a little baffling? How could a `set()` be a worse representation of an actual set than a `list()`?

Among the many consequences of this decision, this code:

```
if d not in miss
```

has been ballooned from O(1) to O(n) time. You should really invest the time into learning how to work with actual sets.

A related block is

```
for rem in range(0, len(c)):
    if len(c[rem]) != len(set(c[rem])):
        remove.append(c[rem])
for rem_two in range(0, len(remove)):
    if remove[rem_two] in c:
        del c[c.index(remove[rem_two])]
```

which is stunning:

- Form a range over the indices of `c` instead of using a standard `for x in c`
- Temporarily make a set, only to throw it out again
- Construct a list of values to remove, instead of a list of indices to remove
- Form another range over the indices of `remove` instead of using a standard `for x in remove`
- Invoke `if in c`, which executes in linear time, within a loop that multiplies it to O(n^2)
- Invoke the linear-time `c.index` on the stored value, instead of just having remembered the index

If all this does is validate input, I don't see why any of this needs to happen, and if it did need to happen it can be done in a vastly simpler way.

If you wanted to keep this validation, a useful validation would apply a `Counter` to the input comprehension and raise a warning (or error) for any count over one. If you wanted to silently collapse lists with repeat elements to sets, this can be done in one line.

Another stunning block is

```
# Throw out lists that have elements that do
# not exist in s.
for j in range(0, len(c)):
    for jj in range(0, len(c[j])):
        if any(elem not in s for elem in c[j]):
            remove_t.append(c[j])
```

This is a loop, containing a nested loop, containing an `any` generator, containing a linear `in s` check. I will leave it as an exercise to you what the computational complexity of this creature is, and how it could be reduced if you convert to real sets.

Comment: Looking forward to this. Optimizing my code means, I am finally done with this hobby-project.